# XSLT 1.0: Filter, Sort, and page a nodeset

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Given the following XML:

```
<A>
  <Photos>
    <Photo>
      <PhotoID>142</PhotoID>
      <PhotoTitle>A</PhotoTitle>
      <Comment />
    </Photo>
    <Photo>
      <PhotoID>143</PhotoID>
      <PhotoTitle>B</PhotoTitle>
      <Comment />
    </Photo>
    <Photo>
      <PhotoID>144</PhotoID>
      <PhotoTitle>C</PhotoTitle>
      <Comment />
    </Photo>
    <Photo>
      <PhotoID>145</PhotoID>
      <PhotoTitle>D</PhotoTitle>
      <Comment />
    </Photo>
    <Photo>
      <PhotoID>146</PhotoID>
      <PhotoTitle>E</PhotoTitle>
      <Comment />
    </Photo>
    <Photo>
      <PhotoID>195</PhotoID>
      <PhotoTitle>F</PhotoTitle>
      <Comment>Foo</Comment>
    </Photo>
    <Photo>
      <PhotoID>196</PhotoID>
      <PhotoTitle>G</PhotoTitle>
      <Comment>Bar</Comment>
    </Photo>
    <Photo>
      <PhotoID>197</PhotoID>
      <PhotoTitle>H</PhotoTitle>
      <Comment>Baz</Comment>
    </Photo>
    <Photo>
      <PhotoID>199</PhotoID>
      <PhotoTitle>F</PhotoTitle>
      <Comment>qux</Comment>
    </Photo>
  </Photos>
</A>
```

I'd like to get HTML output similar to the following:

```
<div id="photoPage" class="page">
    <!-- Page Header Goes Here -->
    <div>
        <h2>Page Title Goes Here</h2>
        <div class="photoBox">
            <!-- Image URL goes here -->
            <div>
                <div>
                  F
                </div>
                <div>
                  Foo
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="photoBox">
            <!-- Image URL goes here -->
            <div>
                <div>
                  F
                </div>
                <div>
                  Qux
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <!-- Page Footer Goes Here -->
</div>
<div id="photoPage" class="page">
    <!-- Page Header Goes Here -->
    <div>
        <h2>Page Title Goes Here</h2>
        <div class="photoBox">
            <!-- Image URL goes here -->
            <div>
                <div>
                  G
                </div>
                <div>
                  Bar
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="photoBox">
            <!-- Image URL goes here -->
            <div>
                <div>
                  H
                </div>
                <div>
                  Baz
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <!-- Page Footer Goes Here -->
</div>
```

In summary, I'm trying to filter to the photos that only include those which have a title of "F", "G", or "H", sorted by title and id, and then split into groups of two. I've been able to accomplish filtering and sorting, but not paging, or paging but not filtering and sorting, but I haven't been able to do all three.

For reference, I'm attempting to do paging similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235060/pagination-in-xsl#12237546).

Here's the approach that's not working:

```
<xsl:template name="Photos">    
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Photos[Photo/PhotoTitle = 'F' or Photo/PhotoTitle = 'G' or Photo/PhotoTitle = 'H']">
        <xsl:sort select="PhotoTitle"/>
        <xsl:sort select="PhotoID"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Photos">
    <xsl:param name="pageSize" select="2"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:for-each select="//Photos/Photo[position() mod $pageSize = 1]">
      <div id="photoPage" class="page">
        <div>
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::*[position() &lt; $pageSize]">
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </div>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Photo">
    <div class="photoBox">
      <!-- img tag -->
      <div>
        <div>
          <xsl:value-of select="./PhotoTitle"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <xsl:value-of select="./Comment"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

The idea is that I explicitly call the first template, which should filter and sort the Photos element, applying the second template, which splits and wraps the Photo elements into two per page, and applies the third template, which outputs and individual Photo.

The results I'm currently getting are neither filtered nor sorted, but are split appropriately. I suspect that is due to the Photos template matching separately from the template that I explicitly call.

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. -- P.S. You say you want groups of three, but I see groups of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The idea is that I explicitly call the first template

I see no such call in the code you have posted. And the second template does `xsl:for-each` selecting **all** `Photo`s, with no filtering by `Title`.

The other problem with your approach is that you cannot use the `following-sibling` axis without copying the filtered nodes first (and, since you're using XSLT 1.0, converting the resulting tree fragment to a node-set, so that it can be processed in second pass).

You also have several syntax errors.

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="A"> 
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Photos"> 
    <xsl:param name="pageSize" select="2"/>
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="photos">
        <xsl:for-each select="Photo[PhotoTitle = 'F' or PhotoTitle = 'G' or PhotoTitle = 'H']">
            <xsl:sort select="PhotoTitle"/>
            <xsl:sort select="PhotoID" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($photos)/Photo[position() mod $pageSize = 1]">
        <div id="photoPage" class="page">
            <div>
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::Photo[position() &lt; $pageSize]"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Photo">
    <div class="photoBox">
      <!-- img tag -->
      <div>
        <div>
          <xsl:value-of select="PhotoTitle"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <xsl:value-of select="Comment"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the result will be:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="photoPage" class="page">
         <div>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <div class="photoBox">
               <div>
                  <div>F</div>
                  <div>Foo</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photoBox">
               <div>
                  <div>F</div>
                  <div>qux</div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="photoPage" class="page">
         <div>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <div class="photoBox">
               <div>
                  <div>G</div>
                  <div>Bar</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photoBox">
               <div>
                  <div>H</div>
                  <div>Baz</div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```